# Send text data from flutter to flask api and webview the returned html

Tags: python, flask, webview, flutter

I have a flutter text entry field. I want to send this text_entry and username to a flask API. The text field may contain latex symbols. Now the flask API will return an HTML file with custom CSS and that text-entry written on it among other things which I can now view in my web browser. I want to webview that returned html file from flutter widget. How to implement it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the http package.
2. Make a network request using the http package.
3. Convert the response into a custom Dart object.
4. Fetch and display the data with Flutter.